# Cannot display two buttons with one button as twice the width of other in GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I need to use `GridLayout` to display two buttons. One and second one with twice the width of other button. I want the `NEXT` button be twice the width of `BACK` button and I need a `GridLayout`.

My source code is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Calculator.Grid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_back_button"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorTextSecondary"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_next_button"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</GridLayout>
```

Desired display (NEXT Button should be double the width of BACK button) :

[image: Desired Display]

But the result is (Problem) :

[image: Result display]

Comment: Do you *need* `GridView`? Or can you wrap `Button`s in a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @Sandeep Shakya Please check my answer is completely work.

Comment: @Abbas Yes i needed a GridLayout in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you don't have any problem with Linear Layout as inner container then use this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="@style/Calculator.Grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
app:rowCount="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_back"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_back_button"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorTextSecondary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_next"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_next_button"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="?attr/colorTextPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>




</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work my bro try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="3">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textViewNW"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnSpan="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
    android:layout_rowSpan="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:background="#fe4141"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/textViewNE"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_columnWeight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="center|fill"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:layout_rowWeight="2"
    android:background="#51f328"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry bro, but this source code resulted a little bit different from what I wanted. The first button is a little bigger than half of the second button. The earlier solution by Mr@Abhishek.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/Calculator.Grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_back_button"
            android:text="@string/back"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorTextSecondary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_next_button"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorTextPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```